# Detect rings/circuits of connected voxels

Tags: computer-vision, graph-theory, image-segmentation, ring, voxel

I have a skeletonized voxel structure that looks like this: [image: example voxel rings]

The actual structure is significantly larger than this exampleIs there any way to find the closed rings in the structure? 
I tried converting it to a graph and using graph based approaches but they all have the problem that a graph has no spatial information of node position and hence a graph can have multiple rings that are homologous.

It is not possible to find all the rings and then filter out the ones of interest since the graph is just too large. The size of the rings varies significantly.

Thanks for your help and contribution!

Any language approaches and pseudo-code are welcomed though I work mostly in Python and Matlab.

---

EDIT:

No the graph is not planar.
The problem with the Graph cycle base is the same as with other simple graph based approaches. The graph lacks any spatial information and different spatial configurations can have the same cycle base, hence the cycle base does not necessarily correspond to the cycles or holes in the graph.

Here is the adjacency matrix in sparse format:

```
NodeID1 NodeID2 Weight
```

[Pastebin with adjacency matrix](https://pastebin.com/Xh7S5Gx1)

And here are the corresponding X,Y,Z coordinates for the Nodes of the graph:

```
X Y Z
```

[Pastebin with node coordinates](https://pastebin.com/r7LmCRGS)

(The actual structure is significantly larger than this example)

Comment: You are not looking for rings, you are looking for holes.

Comment: Can you post an example voxel structure in as a sparse matrix?

Comment: Is the graph planar? In other words, could your x,y,z coordinates be projected on a 2D manifold without changing the topology of the graph? What is the structure that we are looking at? Is it some kind of folded membrane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I reduce the size of the problem considerably by contracting neighbouring nodes of degree 2 into hypernodes: each simple chain in the graph is substituted with a single node.

Then I find the [cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis), for which the maximum cost of the cycles in the basis set is minimal.

For the central part of the network, the solution can easily be plotted as it is planar:

[image]

<s>For some reason, I fail to correctly identify the cycle basis but I think the following should definitely get you started and maybe somebody else can chime in.</s>

#### Recover data from posted image (as OP wouldn't provide some real data)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis, binary_closing
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch
import itertools
import networkx as nx

img = plt.imread("tissue_skeleton_crop.jpg")
# plt.hist(np.mean(img, axis=-1).ravel(), bins=255) # find a good cutoff
bw = np.mean(img, axis=-1) < 200
# plt.imshow(bw, cmap='gray')
closed = binary_closing(bw, selem=np.ones((50,50))) # connect disconnected segments
# plt.imshow(closed, cmap='gray')
skeleton = medial_axis(closed)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.imshow(skeleton, cmap='gray')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

[image]

```
def img_to_graph(binary_img, allowed_steps):
    """
    Arguments:
    ----------
    binary_img    -- 2D boolean array marking the position of nodes
    allowed_steps -- list of allowed steps; e.g. [(0, 1), (1, 1)] signifies that
                     from node with position (i, j) nodes at position (i, j+1)
                     and (i+1, j+1) are accessible,

    Returns:
    --------
    g             -- networkx.Graph() instance
    pos_to_idx    -- dict mapping (i, j) position to node idx (for testing if path exists)
    idx_to_pos    -- dict mapping node idx to (i, j) position (for plotting)
    """

    # map array indices to node indices and vice versa
    node_idx = range(np.sum(binary_img))
    node_pos = zip(*np.where(np.rot90(binary_img, 3)))
    pos_to_idx = dict(zip(node_pos, node_idx))

    # create graph
    g = nx.Graph()
    for (i, j) in node_pos:
        for (delta_i, delta_j) in allowed_steps: # try to step in all allowed directions
            if (i+delta_i, j+delta_j) in pos_to_idx: # i.e. target node also exists
                g.add_edge(pos_to_idx[(i,j)], pos_to_idx[(i+delta_i, j+delta_j)])

    idx_to_pos = dict(zip(node_idx, node_pos))

    return g, idx_to_pos, pos_to_idx

allowed_steps = set(itertools.product((-1, 0, 1), repeat=2)) - set([(0,0)])
g, idx_to_pos, pos_to_idx = img_to_graph(skeleton, allowed_steps)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
nx.draw(g, pos=idx_to_pos, node_size=1, ax=ax)
```

[image]

NB: These are not red lines, these are lots of red dots corresponding to nodes in the graph.

#### Contract Graph

```
def contract(g):
    """
    Contract chains of neighbouring vertices with degree 2 into one hypernode.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    g -- networkx.Graph or networkx.DiGraph instance

    Returns:
    --------
    h -- networkx.Graph or networkx.DiGraph instance
        the contracted graph

    hypernode_to_nodes -- dict: int hypernode -> [v1, v2, ..., vn]
        dictionary mapping hypernodes to nodes

    """

    # create subgraph of all nodes with degree 2
    is_chain = [node for node, degree in g.degree() if degree == 2]
    chains = g.subgraph(is_chain)

    # contract connected components (which should be chains of variable length) into single node
    components = list(nx.components.connected_component_subgraphs(chains))
    hypernode = g.number_of_nodes()
    hypernodes = []
    hyperedges = []
    hypernode_to_nodes = dict()
    false_alarms = []
    for component in components:
        if component.number_of_nodes() > 1:

            hypernodes.append(hypernode)
            vs = [node for node in component.nodes()]
            hypernode_to_nodes[hypernode] = vs

            # create new edges from the neighbours of the chain ends to the hypernode
            component_edges = [e for e in component.edges()]
            for v, w in [e for e in g.edges(vs) if not ((e in component_edges) or (e[::-1] in component_edges))]:
                if v in component:
                    hyperedges.append([hypernode, w])
                else:
                    hyperedges.append([v, hypernode])

            hypernode += 1

        else: # nothing to collapse as there is only a single node in component:
            false_alarms.extend([node for node in component.nodes()])

    # initialise new graph with all other nodes
    not_chain = [node for node in g.nodes() if not node in is_chain]
    h = g.subgraph(not_chain + false_alarms)
    h.add_nodes_from(hypernodes)
    h.add_edges_from(hyperedges)

    return h, hypernode_to_nodes

h, hypernode_to_nodes = contract(g)

# set position of hypernode to position of centre of chain
for hypernode, nodes in hypernode_to_nodes.items():
    chain = g.subgraph(nodes)
    first, last = [node for node, degree in chain.degree() if degree==1]
    path = nx.shortest_path(chain, first, last)
    centre = path[len(path)/2]
    idx_to_pos[hypernode] = idx_to_pos[centre]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
nx.draw(h, pos=idx_to_pos, node_size=20, ax=ax)
```

[image]

#### Find cycle basis

```
cycle_basis = nx.cycle_basis(h)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
nx.draw(h, pos=idx_to_pos, node_size=10, ax=ax)
for cycle in cycle_basis:
    vertices = [idx_to_pos[idx] for idx in cycle]
    path = Path(vertices)
    ax.add_artist(PathPatch(path, facecolor=np.random.rand(3)))
```

#### TODO:

Find the correct cycle basis (I might be confused what the [cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis) is or `networkx` might have a bug).

## EDIT

Holy crap, this was a tour-de-force. I should have never delved into this rabbit hole.

[image]

So the idea is now that we want to find the cycle basis for which the maximum cost for the cycles in the basis is minimal. We set the cost of a cycle to its length in edges, but one could imagine other cost functions. To do so, we find an initial cycle basis, and then we combine cycles in the basis until we find the set of cycles with the desired property.

```
def find_holes(graph, cost_function):
    """
    Find the cycle basis, that minimises the maximum individual cost of the cycles in the basis set.
    """

    # get cycle basis
    cycles = nx.cycle_basis(graph)

    # find new basis set that minimises maximum cost
    old_basis = set()
    new_basis = set(frozenset(cycle) for cycle in cycles) # only frozensets are hashable
    while new_basis != old_basis:
        old_basis = new_basis
        for cycle_a, cycle_b in itertools.combinations(old_basis, 2):
            if len(frozenset.union(cycle_a, cycle_b)) >= 2: # maybe should check if they share an edge instead
                cycle_c = _symmetric_difference(graph, cycle_a, cycle_b)
                new_basis = new_basis.union([cycle_c])
        new_basis = _select_cycles(new_basis, cost_function)

    ordered_cycles = [order_nodes_in_cycle(graph, nodes) for nodes in new_basis]
    return ordered_cycles

def _symmetric_difference(graph, cycle_a, cycle_b):
    # get edges
    edges_a = list(graph.subgraph(cycle_a).edges())
    edges_b = list(graph.subgraph(cycle_b).edges())

    # also get reverse edges as graph undirected
    edges_a += [e[::-1] for e in edges_a]
    edges_b += [e[::-1] for e in edges_b]

    # find edges that are in either but not in both
    edges_c = set(edges_a) ^ set(edges_b)

    cycle_c = frozenset(nx.Graph(list(edges_c)).nodes())
    return cycle_c

def _select_cycles(cycles, cost_function):
    """
    Select cover of nodes with cycles that minimises the maximum cost
    associated with all cycles in the cover.
    """
    cycles = list(cycles)
    costs = [cost_function(cycle) for cycle in cycles]
    order = np.argsort(costs)

    nodes = frozenset.union(*cycles)
    covered = set()
    basis = []

    # greedy; start with lowest cost
    for ii in order:
        cycle = cycles[ii]
        if cycle <= covered:
            pass
        else:
            basis.append(cycle)
            covered |= cycle
            if covered == nodes:
                break

    return set(basis)

def _get_cost(cycle, hypernode_to_nodes):
    cost = 0
    for node in cycle:
        if node in hypernode_to_nodes:
            cost += len(hypernode_to_nodes[node])
        else:
            cost += 1
    return cost

def _order_nodes_in_cycle(graph, nodes):
    order, = nx.cycle_basis(graph.subgraph(nodes))
    return order

holes = find_holes(h, cost_function=partial(_get_cost, hypernode_to_nodes=hypernode_to_nodes))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
nx.draw(h, pos=idx_to_pos, node_size=10, ax=ax)
for ii, hole in enumerate(holes):
    if (len(hole) > 3):
        vertices = np.array([idx_to_pos[idx] for idx in hole])
        path = Path(vertices)
        ax.add_artist(PathPatch(path, facecolor=np.random.rand(3)))
        xmin, ymin = np.min(vertices, axis=0)
        xmax, ymax = np.max(vertices, axis=0)
        x = xmin + (xmax-xmin) / 2.
        y = ymin + (ymax-ymin) / 2.
        # ax.text(x, y, str(ii))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer, but sadly there are some problems with it: The approach you shown I have already implemented. I can create a very clean 3D graph from my initial voxel data. (Maybe this was not so clear and I have attached the data now to my question). The problem with graph based approaches are they lack any spatial information on the Nodes. Hence things like cycle basis are actually not properly defined. Consider the following [graphs](https://sketch.io/render/sk-becd91a30210fc0d0142b8d293ce2d8e.jpeg) They are graph representation wise the same!

Comment: Sure, but you can just keep track of which node corresponds to which position, like I do in my code with the dictionary `idx_to_pos`.

Comment: yes you can keep track of them but the code to compute the cycle basis does not use this information in any sense and no pure graph algorithm will ever ( you can have some of that information by having edge weights but not the full information). When you look at my drawing the cycle basis is going to be the same in both cases, though the structure I'm interested in would be different. That's why the cycle basis you get out of networkx don't seem to correspond to the rings/holes though they are a correct cycle basis.

Comment: If you keep track of the node positions, you can simply (-ish) impose a penalty on cycle basis sets that you don't like. See updated answer.

Comment: Well first of all: A big big thank you for this great in-depth answer. I tried doing dfs and bfs with some penalty on distance travelled but it never occured to me to assemble the cycle base towards the least costs. I haven't tried this on my full graph, but I will play around it in the coming days. It looks promising, but yeah it's definitely a rabbit hole :) minimizing the circumference is not ideal since holes can be concave, but I have already some cost functions in my head that might work. I might get back to you but so far I'm going to accept this great answer. Got some new ideas:)

Comment: Yeah, I thought you might want to use another cost function that would be more related to the "area" of the rings/holes. Also, if a variant of this ends up in a research paper, I want to know about it!

Comment: I'm playing around both with an implementation in Matlab and adopting your python implementation. I was wondering whether you're criterion to abort the cycle selection is correct. In case I have only nodes with degree > 2 (no nodes on lines) the break if all nodes are visited leaves edges out that were visited before. If I change this to all edges visited that were visited before I visit all edges and hence all nodes, but I still end up with less cycles than before. But I thought the number of cycle basis components should never change? Ho do I know I found a proper cycle base?

Comment: The line `new_basis = new_basis.union([cycle_c])` adds a bunch of cycles beyond the basis set. The function `select_cycles` contracts that set again to a basis set. The break within `select_cycles` ensures that we have a proper basis set.

Comment: Yes I totally get that. But you cannot simply check if all nodes have been visited. After breeding about it yesterday I'm sure you have to check whether a cycle is linear independent prior to adding. Say you start with the cheapest cycle, add a second one but then add a third one that is still cheap but actually a linear combination of the first one. Example: Imagine a square with a cross inside: ☒ You have 5 nodes and 8 edges so 8-5+1 = 4 cycles as basis. If you add the left triangle and the right triangle you have all nodes visited but not a full cycle base

Comment: You are right. Can't think about a solution today, but I will think about it on the weekend.

Comment: I think I solved the issue: Instead of keeping track of the nodes for the cycles I create an incidence vector for each cycle. I have m edges. A cycle is now a 1xm bool vector with 1s if the edge is in the cycle and 0s otherwise. Then the symmetric differnence is bitwise xor and I can use boolean gaussian elimination after adding a new cycle and check if get a zero vector in the result. If this is the case the cycle is linear dependent on the already found base and will be rejected and then I can breakout of the loop when the N cycles are found ( or iterate through the rest to check)

Comment: That would work and is much simpler and probably faster than my idea. I was going to change the code such that once I had an initial cycle basis, I would keep track of all possibilities in a kind of solution "multiverse" and then use Viterbi/Baum-Welch to find the optimal set of cycles. Kind of like you would look for the optimal sequence in a hidden Markov model.

Comment: This stuff might actually be useful for people. We should set up repository on github. You write the matlab code, I write the python code, and then we settle on a common API.

Comment: Yeah we should do that. I'm currently optimizing a lot, since I will need this to work on a large graph and since it's rather brute force, there is some optimization in regards to memory and data types that's necessary. Maybe the python version won't need that since you have sets but we can see :)

Comment: My profile lists my website which lists my email address. Shoot me an email when you want to talk.

Comment: Very interesting write up! Did this end up in a codebase as suggested @Paul? I would love to take a look and/or contribute once I tested this with my use case

Comment: @TomHemmes No, sorry we never got to work this out fully. I had to finish my PhD and in the process this fell off my radar. DarkCell also discovered some issues with my approach, so your mileage may vary. I will post his email in the comments below. I think my approach is still an ok heuristic but you should carefully look at your results as there are no guarantees.

Comment: The main issue I have so far discovered are the computational cost of determining whether a ring is linear independent prior to adding them and the other issue is that your approach is not bound to converge or give the optimal solution. 
I.e. it can be the case that if you take 3 circles with costs a, b, c that the new ring a&b has a higher cost than a,b and c but the new ring (a&b) & c might have a lower cost than a,b and c. But it never occurs because the ring a&b is excluded due to its higher costs.

Comment: The main issue here is that for every cost function but the minimum weight one the problem is NP-hard. With careful initialisation the approach still gives a good approximation so I think it’s worthwhile to pursue this.