# python networkx cycles of a circuit

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, scientific-computing

I am attempting to find the current through each edge (branch) in networkx of size LXL. To do this I am using Kirchoff's voltage law which states:[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQqiy.gif)

To setup the simultaneous linear equations I need to find the cycles in a  graph, and as I have an undirected graph I have applied `nx.simple_cycles(G)`, where G is my graph.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joeFR.png)

But this returns some cycles that are correct and some that are wrong. I'm not sure what else to try I have been banging my head against a wall for weeks trying to figure this out. If this fails I'm just going to resort to exporting the network into a SPICE packages and solve for the branch currents using that. Or is there another way to get the currents?

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def gen_random_num():
    return np.random.weibull(a=1.0)

G = nx.Graph()
rows = range(3)
columns = range(3)


#grid algorithm https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/generators/classic.html#grid_graph
G.add_nodes_from( ((i,j) for i in rows for j in columns))

G.add_edges_from( ((i,j),(i-1,j)) for i in rows for j in columns if i>0)
G.add_edges_from( ((i,j),(i,j-1)) for i in rows for j in columns if j>0)   

for n in G.nodes:
    G.node[n]['current'] = int(gen_random_num())

pos = dict((n, n) for n in G.nodes())

node_labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'current')

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=500)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('fig')

cycles = nx.cycle_basis(G)


numedges = G.number_of_edges()
numnodes = G.number_of_nodes()
num_cycles = len(cycles)

for cycle in cycles:
    print(cycle)
```

and this returns:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 1)]
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 1)]
[(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

which is wrong because there should be another cycle in the bottom left mesh.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `cycle_basis` gives you a basis set of cycles from which all other cycles can be constructed through set unions and intersections. It does **not** return all cycles in the graph.

Comment: @Paul - Is there a way to just get the unique cycles? There is `simple_cycles()` but it requires a digraph. I was thinking of creating a digraph by setting a direction for the current perhaps clockwise. Do you know any algorithms I can implement to find the cycles? Or an easier way to calculate the current(s)?

Comment: You just need to take the symmetric difference between each pair of cycles in your basis set, iirc. See answer below (can't past code as a comment).

Comment: This doesn't answer your actual question, but I'm fairly certain that a complete set of KCL equations can *always* be generated from the basis cycles. They might not be the simplest/shortest possible equations, but that probably doesn't matter if you're solving the equations programmatically.

Comment: @mbrig Yeah I'm aware you can have so called 'super meshes' and solve them. Guess I could always try it out and see if I can prove it later on.

Answer (score 0):

`cycle_basis` returns a basis set of cycles, not all cycles in the graph. Expand your cycle basis to a collection of all cycles by iterating over all pairs and computing the symmetric difference.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def symmetric_difference(graph, cycle_a, cycle_b):
    # get edges
    edges_a = list(graph.subgraph(cycle_a).edges())
    edges_b = list(graph.subgraph(cycle_b).edges())

    # also get reverse edges as graph undirected
    edges_a += [e[::-1] for e in edges_a]
    edges_b += [e[::-1] for e in edges_b]

    # find edges that are in either but not in both
    edges_c = set(edges_a) ^ set(edges_b)

    cycle_c = frozenset(nx.Graph(list(edges_c)).nodes())
    return cycle_c

def gen_random_num():
    return np.random.weibull(a=1.0)

G = nx.Graph()
rows = range(3)
columns = range(3)

#grid algorithm https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/generators/classic.html#grid_graph
G.add_nodes_from( ((i,j) for i in rows for j in columns))
G.add_edges_from( ((i,j),(i-1,j)) for i in rows for j in columns if i>0)
G.add_edges_from( ((i,j),(i,j-1)) for i in rows for j in columns if j>0)

for n in G.nodes:
    G.node[n]['current'] = int(gen_random_num())

pos = dict((n, n) for n in G.nodes())
node_labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'current')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=500)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('fig')

cycle_basis = nx.cycle_basis(G)
cycles = []
for c1, c2 in itertools.combinations(cycle_basis, 2):
    cycles.append(list(symmetric_difference(G, c1, c2)))
cycles += cycle_basis

for cycle in cycles:
    print(cycle)

# [(1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 1), (0, 2), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0), (0, 2)]
# [(1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
# [(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
# [(1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 1), (0, 2), (2, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
# [(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 1)]
# [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
# [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 1)]
# [(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks let me try it out in a notebook.

Comment: it's still returning cycles I do not want (like super cycles). Perhaps I need to do more filtering?

Comment: Could it be that you do not want all cycles, but the effectively this set: [(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 1)], [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)], [(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)], and [(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)]? If so, you should probably look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633840/detect-rings-circuits-of-connected-voxels/43648552#43648552