# Graph reduction

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have been working on an piece of code to reduce a graph. The problem is that there are some branches that I want to remove. Once I remove a branch I can merge the nodes or not, depending on the number of paths between the nodes the branch joined.

Maybe the following example illustrates what I want:

[image]

The code I have is the following:

```
from networkx import DiGraph, all_simple_paths, draw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# data preparation
branches = [(2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (4,13), (7,6), (6,5), (5,4), 
            (8,7), (9,8), (9,10), (10,11), (11,12), (12,1), (13,9)]

branches_to_remove_idx = [11, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 0]
ft_dict = dict()
graph = DiGraph()

for i, br in enumerate(branches):
    graph.add_edge(br[0], br[1])
    ft_dict[i] = (br[0], br[1])

# Processing -----------------------------------------------------
for idx in branches_to_remove_idx:

    # get the nodes that define the edge to remove
    f, t = ft_dict[idx]

    # get the number of paths from 'f' to 't'
    n_paths = len(list(all_simple_paths(graph, f, t)))

    if n_paths == 1:
        # remove branch and merge the nodes 'f' and 't'
        #
        #       This is what I have no clue how to do
        #
        pass

    else:
        # remove the branch and that's it
        graph.remove_edge(f, t)
        print('Simple removal of', f, t)

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

draw(graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

I feel that there should be a simpler direct way to obtain the last figure from the first, given the branch indices, but I have no clue.

Comment: In "network speak", what you call branches are usually called "edges".

Comment: shall I change it?

Comment: If you want. It is still understandable.

Comment: Also, what is the overall goal here? You say that you want to remove "branches" (edges), but then you remove nodes and connect the neighbours. Is it fair to say that you want to simplify networks by minimizing the number of nodes while keeping the number of cycles constant? Or do you want to explicitly define the nodes or edges that you want removed (as stated in the question at the moment)?

Comment: The problem at hand is the removal of branches (edges) in an electrical grid with impedance close to zero. This means that those branches do not change the calculation significantly if the two nodes they join are merged. But by removing the edges and merging the nodes, the grid is still "the same" but with a lower computational demand for calculation. On the example I have the potential edge reduction is from 4500 to 700. Those edges are represented for engineering and maintenance reasons but are a burden for calculation.

Comment: I wrote the code for the answer that I posted below for a [very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633840/detect-rings-circuits-of-connected-voxels/43648552#43648552). I think it should apply in this case, too.

Comment: Thanks, I will review it in detail

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more or less what you want. I am merging all nodes that are in chains (connected nodes of degree 2) into one hypernode. I return the the new graph and a dictionary mapping the hypernode to the contracted nodes.

```
import networkx as nx

def contract(g):
    """
    Contract chains of neighbouring vertices with degree 2 into one hypernode.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    g -- networkx.Graph instance

    Returns:
    --------
    h -- networkx.Graph instance
        the contracted graph

    hypernode_to_nodes -- dict: int hypernode -> [v1, v2, ..., vn]
        dictionary mapping hypernodes to nodes

    """

    # create subgraph of all nodes with degree 2
    is_chain = [node for node, degree in g.degree_iter() if degree == 2]
    chains = g.subgraph(is_chain)

    # contract connected components (which should be chains of variable length) into single node
    components = list(nx.components.connected_component_subgraphs(chains))
    hypernode = max(g.nodes()) +1
    hypernodes = []
    hyperedges = []
    hypernode_to_nodes = dict()
    false_alarms = []
    for component in components:
        if component.number_of_nodes() > 1:

            hypernodes.append(hypernode)
            vs = [node for node in component.nodes()]
            hypernode_to_nodes[hypernode] = vs

            # create new edges from the neighbours of the chain ends to the hypernode
            component_edges = [e for e in component.edges()]
            for v, w in [e for e in g.edges(vs) if not ((e in component_edges) or (e[::-1] in component_edges))]:
                if v in component:
                    hyperedges.append([hypernode, w])
                else:
                    hyperedges.append([v, hypernode])

            hypernode += 1

        else: # nothing to collapse as there is only a single node in component:
            false_alarms.extend([node for node in component.nodes()])

    # initialise new graph with all other nodes
    not_chain = [node for node in g.nodes() if not node in is_chain]
    h = g.subgraph(not_chain + false_alarms)
    h.add_nodes_from(hypernodes)
    h.add_edges_from(hyperedges)

    return h, hypernode_to_nodes


edges = [(2, 1),
         (3, 2),
         (4, 3),
         (4, 13),
         (7, 6),
         (6, 5),
         (5, 4),
         (8, 7),
         (9, 8),
         (9, 10),
         (10, 11),
         (11, 12),
         (12, 1),
         (13, 9)]

g = nx.Graph(edges)

h, hypernode_to_nodes = contract(g)

print("Edges in contracted graph:")
print(h.edges())
print('')
print("Hypernodes:")
for hypernode, nodes in hypernode_to_nodes.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(hypernode, nodes))
```

This returns for your example:

```
Edges in contracted graph:
[(9, 13), (9, 14), (9, 15), (4, 13), (4, 14), (4, 15)]

Hypernodes:
14 : [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
15 : [8, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I built this function that scales much better and runs faster with larger graphs:

```py
def add_dicts(vector):
    l = list(map(lambda x: Counter(x),vector))
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,l)

def consolidate_dup_edges(g):
    edges = pd.DataFrame(g.edges(data=True),columns=['start','end','weight'])
    edges_consolidated = edges.groupby(['start','end']).agg({'weight':add_dicts}).reset_index()
    return nx.from_edgelist(list(edges_consolidated.itertuples(index=False,name=None)))

def graph_reduce(g):
    g = consolidate_dup_edges(g)
    is_deg2 = [node for node, degree in g.degree() if degree == 2]
    is_deg2_descendents =list(map(lambda x: tuple(nx.descendants_at_distance(g,x,1)),is_deg2))
    edges_on_deg2= list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda x:x[2],g.edges(x,data=True))),is_deg2))
    edges_on_deg2= list(map(lambda x: add_dicts(x),edges_on_deg2))
    new_edges = list(zip(is_deg2_descendents,edges_on_deg2))
    new_edges = [(a,b,c) for (a,b),c in new_edges]
    g.remove_nodes_from(is_deg2)
    g.add_edges_from(new_edges)
    g.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(g))
    g.remove_nodes_from([node for node, degree in g.degree() if degree <= 1])
    return consolidate_dup_edges(g)
```

The `graph_reduce` function basically removes nodes with degree 1 and removes intermediate nodes with degree 2 and connects the nodes that the degree 2 node was connected to. We can see the best impact when we run this code iteratively until the number of nodes plateaus to a stable number. This only works on undirected graphs.

[image: graph reduction on 10k nodes]